# My executable jar doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, export, executable-jar

I've been working all night long in a project using javafx in "eclipse". It worked perfectly so I pressed "export to get the runnable jar file and when I got it, it just didn't work and still doesn't. I guess the problem is in the main method, which I'll post here. Any help would be awesome.

```
package recetas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import recetas.model.Receta;
import recetas.model.RecetasListWrapper;
import recetas.view.Controlador;
import recetas.view.ControladorEditar;
import recetas.view.VerControlador;



public class MainRecetas extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private ObservableList<Receta> recetaData = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList();

    public MainRecetas() {
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Arroz tres delicias"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Pollo al horno"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Bizcocho de chocolate"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Pizza barbacoa"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Sopa de pescado"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Macarrones a la bolognesa"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Pechuga con patatas fritas"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Macedonia"));
        recetaData.add(new Receta("Fresas con chocolate"));
        recetaData.get(1).setVal(1);
        recetaData.get(1).setPlato("Plato");
        recetaData.get(1).setDif("Facil");
        recetaData.get(2).setDif("Dificil");
    }

    public ObservableList<HBox> getCajasList() {
        ObservableList<HBox> res = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < recetaData.size(); i++)
            res.add(recetaData.get(i).getCaja());
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Mis recetillas");
        this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("@../../icono.png"));
        showPersonOverview();
    }

    public void showPersonOverview() {
        Controlador controller = null;
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainRecetas.class.getResource("view/Vista.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(personOverview);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainRecetas(this);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file = getFilePath();
        if (file != null){
            CargarRecetas(file);
            controller.setMainRecetas(this);
        }
    }

    public boolean editar(Receta r) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainRecetas.class
                    .getResource("view/VentanaEditar.fxml"));
            AnchorPane editar = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialog = new Stage();
            dialog.setTitle("Editar receta: " + r.getNombre());
            dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(editar);
            dialog.setScene(scene);
            ControladorEditar controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setDialogStage(dialog);
            controller.setReceta(r);
            dialog.showAndWait();
            return controller.getOK();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean nuevo() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainRecetas.class
                    .getResource("view/VentanaEditar.fxml"));
            AnchorPane editar = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialog = new Stage();
            Receta r = new Receta(null);
            dialog.setTitle("Nueva receta");
            dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(editar);
            dialog.setScene(scene);
            ControladorEditar controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setDialogStage(dialog);
            controller.setReceta(r);
            dialog.showAndWait();
            boolean ok = controller.getOK();
            if (ok)
                recetaData.add(0, r);
            return ok;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ver(Receta r) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainRecetas.class
                    .getResource("view/VerReceta.fxml"));
            AnchorPane editar = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialog = new Stage();
            dialog.setTitle(r.getNombre());
            dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(editar);
            dialog.setScene(scene);
            VerControlador controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setReceta(r);
            dialog.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void ayuda() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainRecetas.class
                    .getResource("view/Ayuda.fxml"));
            AnchorPane editar = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialog = new Stage();
            dialog.setTitle("Ayuda");
            dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(editar);
            dialog.setScene(scene);
            dialog.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public ObservableList<Receta> getRecetaData() {
        return recetaData;
    }

    public void eliminar(int i) {
        recetaData.remove(i);
    }

    public void setFilePath(File file) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainRecetas.class);
        if (file != null) {
            prefs.put("filePath", file.getPath());

            primaryStage.setTitle("Mis recetillas - " + file.getName());
        } else {
            prefs.remove("filePath");

            primaryStage.setTitle("Mis recetillas");
        }
    }

    public File getFilePath() {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainRecetas.class);
        String filePath = prefs.get("filePath", null);
        if (filePath != null) {
            return new File(filePath);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void CargarRecetas(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(RecetasListWrapper.class);
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

            RecetasListWrapper wrapper = (RecetasListWrapper) um
                    .unmarshal(file);

            recetaData.clear();
            try{ recetaData.addAll(wrapper.getRecetas());}
            catch(NullPointerException e){}

            setFilePath(file);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("No se pudo cargar la información del archivo:\n"
                    + file.getPath());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public void guardarRecetas(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(RecetasListWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            RecetasListWrapper wrapper = new RecetasListWrapper();
            wrapper.setRecetas(recetaData);

            m.marshal(wrapper, file);

            setFilePath(file);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("No se pudo guardar la información en el archivo:\n"
                    + file.getPath());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public List<Receta> buscarDestacadas() {
        List<Receta> l = new ArrayList<Receta>();
        for (int i = 0; i < recetaData.size(); i++) {
            Receta r = recetaData.get(i);
            if (r.getVal() == 5)
                l.add(r);
        }
        return l;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: by `doesn't work`, do you mean it crashes? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: run it from the commandline and post the stacktrace

Comment: I double-click on it and it just doesn't run. It doesn't give any error, just like if I hadn't clicked.

Comment: And in the commandline there's also no report of an error

Comment: `..` will not work in a jar neither will the `@` symbol (I don't even know what the @ is supposed to mean), so remove `@../../icono.png`, place the icon in the root of the jar file and reference it via `/icono.png`.  Also make sure your fxml files and resources they reference are in the right place.  If you still have issues, it may benefit you just trying to package a basic hello world application as a jar, and then gradually add back in functionality from your program a piece at a time until it breaks - then you will have a better idea what the error is. Also run `java -jar yourapp.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the events described in the comments and with the code you have given I have two possible solutions.

1. From the code you have given, there is no `launch()` method.  This means once started the program will go no where and it should produce an error because there is no method `launch()`.
2. You might have exported it as something other than an executable.  Perhaps you have exported it as a `jar file` and not a `runnable jar file`.  If you did this all you have to do is change how you export it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, but I initialized photos in start method (which only use in JavaFX), and my problem has been solved and jar works same as working in IDE (Eclipse in my case).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
  // set all photos in this function
}
```

**Notice in Eclipse IDE:**

1. set JDK instead of JRE in installed JREs
2. create special JavaFX project from File->New->Project->JavaFX->JavaFX project
3. build project by "build.fxbuild" and after that, export just like the normal Java programs
4. set all icons and photos in start method and never define icons or any photos in another functions.